# Custom button not working in AVPlayer iOS 11 but it's perfectly working below iOS 11?

Tags: ios, objective-c, avplayer, ios11, avplayerviewcontroller

I know possibly this is duplicate question but the question which is already exist didn't have an solution so , I'm asking again to possibly start bounty question .

Here is my code which is working below iOS 11 :

```
AVPlayer *player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:videoURL];

// create a player view controller
avcontroller = [[AVPlayerViewController alloc]init];
avcontroller.player = player;
[player play];


NSNotificationCenter *noteCenter = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
[noteCenter addObserverForName:AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification
                        object:nil
                         queue:nil
                    usingBlock:^(NSNotification *note) {

                        NSLog(@"Video end");
                        self.avcontroller.player = nil;
                        [self.avcontroller.view removeFromSuperview];
                        [self.view addSubview:delegate.tabViewControllerObj.tabBarController.view];
                    }];

_skip =[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[_skip addTarget:self action:@selector(btnSkipTapped)
 forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[_skip setTitle:@"Skip" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
_skip.layer.borderWidth = 2.0f;
_skip.layer.cornerRadius = 12; 
_skip.clipsToBounds = YES;
_skip.layer.borderColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;

// show the view controller
[self addChildViewController:avcontroller];
[avcontroller.view addSubview:_skip];
[avcontroller.view bringSubviewToFront:_skip];
[self.view addSubview:avcontroller.view];
avcontroller.view.frame = self.view.frame;

}

-(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews{
  [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];

 _skip.frame = CGRectMake((self.view.frame.size.width-140),(self.view.frame.size.height-150),100.0,35.0);
}
```

And here is button tapped function:

```
- (IBAction)btnSkipTapped{

NSLog(@"Skip button clicked");
self.avcontroller.player = nil;
[self.avcontroller.view removeFromSuperview];
[self.view addSubview:delegate.tabViewControllerObj.tabBarController.view];
}
```

This code will display button perfectly but upon button tap , it didn't call btnSkipTapped function. 
Any help would be appreciated !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@DeepShah you have added skip button in `avcontroller.view` so its display proper but you can't click on it because `AVPlayerViewControllerContentView` covers that skip button.

**see below image :**

[image]

so you have to add skip button in `self.view` and its works.

```
[self.view addSubview:_skip];
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:_skip];
```

Comment: I face the same problem.In my case I present the AVPlayerViewController and add a custom button.A button is shown on the AVPlayerViewController but can not trigger button action.I tried to do what you mentioned above but did not work.This issue is occurred  only in iOS 11.

let btn = UIButton(type: .custom) as UIButton
            self.playerViewController.view?.addSubview(btn)
            self.playerViewController.view?.bringSubview(toFront: self.castWrapperView)
            self.present(self.playerViewController, animated: false, completion: nil)

@Nirav any idea about this matter ?

Comment: added in `self.view` or `self.playerViewController.view` ?

Comment: try to add in `self.view`

Comment: self.view?.addSubview(btn)
self.view?.bringSubview(toFront: btn)

Now button is not shown on player view

Comment: can you give me code ? so i can check it. in dropbox or anywhere code link. if possible then

Comment: You can download sample project here https://www.dropbox.com/s/h3jzbugymzlpi1c/playertest.zip?dl=0

Comment: @Nirav Kotecha ,I found the solution.I will add it as an answer for this question.Thanking for you time and consideration.

Comment: @PramukaD i got a solution. you have to add button in `UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.addSubview(btn)` and remove below 2 line `self.aPlayerViewController.view.addSubview(btn)` `self.aPlayerViewController.view.bringSubview(toFront: btn)`

Comment: I did what you mentioned in above comment.Now button action can be triggered but when dismiss ,button is shown in previous view.anyway I can manage it.Thanks